# Is there a first order formula that is satisfied by $\mathbb{N}$, but not by any other models of Peano axioms?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models

Is there a first order formula that is satisfied by $\mathbb{N}$, but not by any other models of Peano axioms? For example, is there a formula that expresses "there is an element that is greater than any natural number"? My first try was $$\exists v_0 (0<v_0 \wedge \forall (v_1\; v_1<v_0 \Rightarrow Sv_1 <v_0)). $$ But I see that this formula is not true in non-standard models either, because every non-zero element has a predecessor.

Comment: A quick comment on the answers below: note that they are somewhat non-constructive, in the sense that they don't really exhibit a nonstandard model of $Th(\mathbb{N})$. This turns out to be unavoidable in a precise sense: [Tennenbaum proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem) that there is no computable nonstandard model of $I\Sigma_1$, an extremely weak theory of arithmetic. So while there are lots of nonstandard models, there aren't any "simply describable" nonstandard models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can appeal to Gödel's incompleteness theorem: clearly the Peano axioms plus your one axiom are still recursively enumerable, and clearly they are strong enough to encode arithmetic (since they contain the Peano axioms). Thus the theory must be incomplete, and in particular have more than one model by Gödel's *completeness* theorem.

Comment: +1. To the OP, note that this gives a stronger result than asked for: we don't just get non-isomorphic models, we get non-*elementarily-equivalent* models. This can't be done via compactness alone - Godel's incompleteness theorem plays a crucial role. (Compactness does give a strong "coarse" result however which incompleteness doesn't, namely that **no** infinite structure can be characterized up to isomorphism by a first-order theory.)

Answer (score 3):

No.

Take any ultrapower of $\Bbb N$ by a free ultrafilter and you have a non-standard model which is elementarily equivalent to $\Bbb N$. If you want a countable model, simply take a countable elementary submodel of that ultrapower defined by some non-standard integer.

---

Alternatively, note that $\operatorname{Th}(\Bbb N)$ is a first-order theory, and since it has a pointwise definable model (i.e. a model in which every object is definable, in this case $\Bbb N$ is that model where every object is definable by $S\dots S0$ for the appropriate amount of $S$s), it is not categorical in that cardinality. In other words, it has more countable models. Or, again, if cardinality is not important, just note that it is a first-order theory extending $\sf PA$, and since it has an infinite model, it has one of any cardinality.

Comment: +1 (to the OP, if you're not familiar with ultraproducts you can just apply [compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactness_theorem) - one of the proofs of which is via ultraproducts).

Comment: Another comment to the OP, not worth a separate answer: you may reasonably ask **how far beyond first-order logic** you have to go to characterize the standard model of arithmetic. The situation here is perhaps surprising: while obviously both **second-order logic** and **infinitary logic(s)** are enough, beyond this there are some real subtleties. For example, existential second-order formulas are preserved upwards by ultrapowers, so existential second-order logic can't characterize $\mathbb{N}$ (or indeed *any* infinite structure) up to isomorphism, via the same argument.

Comment: @NoahSchweber How do we use the compactness theorem here? Could you explain more?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I plan to read about these when I finish reading my textbook on first order logic.

Comment: @Jiu: You add a constant symbol $c$, and axioms $0<c$, $S0<c$, etc. Throw in the whole of the theory of $\Bbb N$, and you get a theory that is finitely consistent, and any model is elementarily equivalent to $\Bbb N$, but not isomorphic to it.

Comment: @Jiu There's a standard trick we can use here: **expanding the language** (and then taking a reduct). Add a constant symbol $c$ to our language and consider the full first-order theory of $\mathbb{N}$ (in the original language of arithmetic) together with $\{\underline{n}<c:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $\underline{n}$ is the numeral corresponding to $n$ (e.g. $\underline{3}$ is $(1+1)+1$). By compactness this theory has a model; now take the reduct of such a model to the original language of arithmetic and show that it's nonstandard (think about what $c$ could be ...).

Comment: I got it now. Thanks to you both for your answers and comments!

Comment: Is $\mathbb N$ the only pointwise definable model of PA?

Comment: @eyeballfrog: No. Take a model in which $\lnot\operatorname{Con}\sf (PA)$ is true; then take the least proof of $0=1$ from $\sf PA$ in that model, call that $c$. Now consider the elementary submodel generated by $\{c\}$, in that model every number is definable from $c$, but $c$ itself is also definable.

Comment: @eyeballfrog More generally, for every $M\models\mathsf{PA}$ the subset $Def(M)$ of all parameter-freely-definable elements of $M$ is an elementary substructure of $M$ - hence $Def(M)$ is pointwise-definable and satisfies $\mathsf{PA}$. Now take any $M$ with a definable nonstandard element (e.g. $M\models\neg Con(\mathsf{PA})$ as Asaf says, but we have other options). The point is that $\mathsf{PA}$ has definable Skolem functions ("pick the least witness"); the same idea works for $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$ ("pick the $L$-least witness") and many other theories.